Add a Widget to WooCommerce Checkout Order Review before submit button
I am attempting to add the Yotpo Rewards Checkout widget to WooCommerce checkout form right below the area where the total is shown for the transaction for a better user experience. However, when I add the script that I am currently using to functions.php it shows the widget for a couple of seconds and then it disappears.
The Yotpo team seems stumped on this and have said the loader script isn't rendering correctly, but I'm seeing the correct amount of rewards points every time, even when I adjust the points, and I've tried adding the loader script right in the code where the widget code is as well, and it still disappears.
I've also looked in the DOM and can confirm that the loader script is there with the correct information. Here is my current implementation in my theme's functions.php file:
function add_yotpo_widget_to_checkout() {
    echo '<div><script src="https://cdn-widgetsrepository.yotpo.com/v1/loader/<our-key>" async></script><div class="yotpo-widget-instance" data-yotpo-instance-id="<our-instance-id>"></div></div>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'add_yotpo_widget_to_checkout');

As stated above, the widget does show up and is working fine but disappears after a couple of seconds.

As Order review section is Ajax refreshed, you need to make that in a different way:
// Utility function: Get/Output Yotpo widget html
function get_yotpo_widget_html() {
    $yotpo_key = '<our-key>'; // Define the key
    $yotpo_instance_id = '<our-instance-id>'; // Define the instance ID
    return '<script src="https://cdn-widgetsrepository.yotpo.com/v1/loader/'.$yotpo_key.'" async></script>
    <div class="yotpo-widget-instance" data-yotpo-instance-id="'.$yotpo_instance_id.'"></div>';
}

// Display Yotpo widget on checkout
add_action('woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'add_yotpo_widget_to_checkout');
function add_yotpo_widget_to_checkout() {
    echo '<div class="yotpo-widget-container">'.get_yotpo_widget_html().'</div>';
}

// Get refreshed fragments for displayed Yotpo widget on checkout (mandatory)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_update_order_review_fragments', 'update_yotpo_widget_checkout_fragments');
function update_yotpo_widget_checkout_fragments( $fragments ){
    // We add the selector class of our wrapper div as array key
    $fragments['.yotpo-widget-container'] = get_yotpo_widget_html();
    
    return $fragments;
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).
It should work on Classic checkout, but not in new Checkout Block.

Addition:
If it doesn't work, you should try:

To embed the script part in the footer via wp_footer hook (targeting checkout),
To use your original code with one of the following action hooks (not ajax refereshed):

woocommerce_review_order_before_payment
woocommerce_review_order_after_payment




Related:
Update dynamically custom content on WooCommerce update checkout event

I just tried this and it still disappears from the screen after a second or two.

Are you using new Checkout Block or Classic Checkout? This only works in Classic checkout.

I am using the [woocommerce_checkout] shortcode to add the checkout to the correct screen.  I'm not sure if that's Checkout Block or not.

You are using Classic checkout… As I don't use Yotpo Rewards Checkout widget, I can't really test that. I have added an addition to my answer.

Thank you for the additional information.  I'll look into checkout block.  What exactly is Checkout Block?

As Checkout Block doesn't really allow customizations (or just some few), you should stay on Classic checkout.

It does look like woocommerce_review_order_before_payment and woocommerce_review_order_after_payment both seem to work!
